# Category list with postcount

Tags: categories, list

Im total noob with wordpress, and would like to get some help with following problem.

I Would like to make list of all categories and postcounts in category, something like this:

```
category1(2), category2(4), category3(7)
```

with hyperlinks to the category page. If someone could help me with this one with noob friendly answer i would appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use wp_list_categories function with param show_count set to true

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

```
wp_list_categories( array(
'show_count' => true,
'title_li' => '<h2>' . __( 'Categories', 'textdomain' ) . '</h2>') );
```